# Issues parsing a JSON file from a database into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have created an SQL database using PHPmyAdmin which stores JSON files, the idea is to use these files with the Google Maps API to place markers on a map.

I am having trouble converting the JSON file to a JavaScript Object.

after retrieving the json from the database and converting it to a JS format, i assigned it to a variable.

For display purposes I have shown the way I get the String from PHP:

`var jsonString ='<?php echo implode(" ", $firstJsonString); ?>'`

As well as the actual string:

```
var jsonString = '{"address_components":[{"long_name":"London","short_name":"London","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"London","short_name":"London","types":["postal_town"]},{"long_name":"Greater London","short_name":"Greater London","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"England","short_name":"England","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United Kingdom","short_name":"GB","types":["country","political"]}],"adr_address":"<span class="locality">London</span>, <span class="country-name">UK</span>","formatted_address":"London, UK","geometry":{"location":{"lat":51.5073509,"lng":-0.12775829999998223},"viewport":{"south":51.38494009999999,"west":-0.351468299999965,"north":51.6723432,"east":0.14827100000002247}},"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png","id":"b1a8b96daab5065cf4a08f953e577c34cdf769c0","name":"London","photos":[{"height":800,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100576107799945331393/photos">Edu Sousa</a>"],"width":1200},{"height":1065,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117641363844967821087/photos">Manuel Ligabue</a>"],"width":1600},{"height":1365,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107957051173910448327/photos">David Sun</a>"],"width":2048},{"height":2136,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110744511144480687702/photos">Nuno Martins</a>"],"width":3216},{"height":3000,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/118133211030153942640/photos">Roberto Gerosa</a>"],"width":4000},{"height":3024,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102674303425902835965/photos">ALLWYN D&#39;SILVA</a>"],"width":4032},{"height":1080,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111050241231844820150/photos">Cristina Cunsolo</a>"],"width":1920},{"height":1362,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101001561862058426912/photos">Dendy Legends</a>"],"width":2048},{"height":1440,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111849553513496073867/photos">Destiny Symonee</a>"],"width":2560},{"height":1452,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109648577636572315039/photos">Leslie</a>"],"width":5248}],"place_id":"ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI","reference":"CmRbAAAAw49v9euZCWzrvjJ9b8STdg4qK48YueqQIOMerhQ43OP-NynPqFygwZnFzb-jcKkRKJog7z2IeUubF468akLhMj7pIZSoOWFXGjKC0WgkubgTIRlySRkBM47V9RMcX5YoEhB3qYHCQ3roB1G_gHnh_i8MGhSbxmofinNGCLquqddTEQ3DjsKOcg","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["locality","political"],"url":"https://maps.google.com/?q=London,+UK&ftid=0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99","utc_offset":60,"vicinity":"London","html_attributions":[]} {"address_components":[{"long_name":"London","short_name":"London","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"London","short_name":"London","types":["postal_town"]},{"long_name":"Greater London","short_name":"Greater London","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"England","short_name":"England","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United Kingdom","short_name":"GB","types":["country","political"]}],"adr_address":"<span class="locality">London</span>, <span class="country-name">UK</span>","formatted_address":"London, UK","geometry":{"location":{"lat":51.5073509,"lng":-0.12775829999998223},"viewport":{"south":51.38494009999999,"west":-0.351468299999965,"north":51.6723432,"east":0.14827100000002247}},"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png","id":"b1a8b96daab5065cf4a08f953e577c34cdf769c0","name":"London","photos":[{"height":800,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100576107799945331393/photos">Edu Sousa</a>"],"width":1200},{"height":1065,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117641363844967821087/photos">Manuel Ligabue</a>"],"width":1600},{"height":1365,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107957051173910448327/photos">David Sun</a>"],"width":2048},{"height":2136,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110744511144480687702/photos">Nuno Martins</a>"],"width":3216},{"height":3000,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/118133211030153942640/photos">Roberto Gerosa</a>"],"width":4000},{"height":3024,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102674303425902835965/photos">ALLWYN D&#39;SILVA</a>"],"width":4032},{"height":1080,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111050241231844820150/photos">Cristina Cunsolo</a>"],"width":1920},{"height":1362,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101001561862058426912/photos">Dendy Legends</a>"],"width":2048},{"height":1440,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111849553513496073867/photos">Destiny Symonee</a>"],"width":2560},{"height":1452,"html_attributions":["<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109648577636572315039/photos">Leslie</a>"],"width":5248}],"place_id":"ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI","reference":"CmRbAAAAw49v9euZCWzrvjJ9b8STdg4qK48YueqQIOMerhQ43OP-NynPqFygwZnFzb-jcKkRKJog7z2IeUubF468akLhMj7pIZSoOWFXGjKC0WgkubgTIRlySRkBM47V9RMcX5YoEhB3qYHCQ3roB1G_gHnh_i8MGhSbxmofinNGCLquqddTEQ3DjsKOcg","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["locality","political"],"url":"https://maps.google.com/?q=London,+UK&ftid=0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99","utc_offset":60,"vicinity":"London","html_attributions":[]}';
```

Here I attempt to convert it to an object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(obj);
```

However when run I get an error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 492**

I checked position 492, this is at the point where there is an '=' symbol.
Looking at it now, I believe this is the first occurence of an "=" symbol in this JSON string.

Why is this = symbol causing this error, and how can I prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to convert JavaScriptObjectNotation to javascript objects.:D

Comment: What is `$firstJsonString`, and why are you calling `implode()`?

Comment: `require_once('getMarkers.php');
$markerArray = getMarkers();
$firstJsonString = $markerArray[0];`

its the first string from my array of Json Strings from the database, i was imploding since If i just did $firstJsonString, it would just say "Array" instead of the desired string.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to parse the JSON. JSON is a JavaScript Object Notation, so you can get rid of the strings and it will declare a JavaScript object for you to use.

You can use https://jsonlint.com to validate your JSON

Edit

Your JSON is incorrect. Near `"adr_address": "<span class="` there is an error in your JSON. You should solve that first.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that in the process of uploading the file to the database, the JSON is becoming invalid. At somepoint the backslash character \ is being removed and therefore invalidating my Json.